# Comparing ArrayList in a unit test

Tags: java, junit

Hello I was trying to test assertEquals() with an ArrayList.
This is a part of my test code:

```
ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
n.add("a");
n.add("b");
n.add("c");
assertEquals(n, "[a, b, c]");
```

It looks like exactly same to me, but the junit says

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[a, b, c]> but was:<[a, b, c]>
```

Could anyone point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing a list to a string

Try something like

```
List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
expected.add("a");
expected.add("b");
expected.add("c");
assertEquals(expected,n);
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is a List whereas `"[a, b, c]"` is a string - the latter is a (possible) representation of the former but they are definitely not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing with a `String` won't work, but you don't need to create an `ArrayList` specifically to make the comparison, any `List` will do. Therefore you can use the method [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
assertEquals(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare arrays instead of lists:

```
  List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
  expected.add("1");
  expected.add("2");
  expected.add("3");
  Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected.toArray(), new String[]{"1", "2", "3"});
```